# How do I get rid of black bars obscuring text in a PDF printout?

Tags: ios, pdf

On iOS 11, and possibly earlier versions, we have seen instances where a generated PDF file [using UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData()/UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()] looks fine on screen and on some printers, but on other printers (such as the HP ColorLaser M551 and HP LaserJet Enterprise M806) lines of text appear as black bars instead. How do we get rid of the black bars for all media and printers?

Note: The bars are only black for black text. The bar colors appear to match the intended text colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much investigation, I discovered that the problem only occurs for UILabel text where the UILabel is added as a subview to a UIView whose layer is subsequently rendered into the PDF context. The workaround is to render the text directly into the PDF context, using CTLineDraw() and its support routines from CoreText, after rendering the UIView.

UPDATE: Apple suggests drawing the page into a bitmap first, then drawing the bitmap into the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Using a UITextField instead of UILabel works as well.

Comment: Yes, "the problem only occurs for UILabel text".